# Criteria for deciding which character columns should be converted to factors

Tags: r

I have been working through the book "Analyzing Baseball Data with R" by Marchi and Albert and am wondering about an issue which they don't address.

Many of the datasets I need to import are fairly large (though not really "Big" in the sense of "Big Data"). For example, the [Retrosheet Game Logs](http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/index.html) have 1 csv file per year dating back to 1871 where each file has a row for each game played that year, and 161 columns. When I read it into a dataframe using `read.csv()` using the default setting on `stringsAsFactors` fully 75 of the 161 columns become factors. Some of these columns conceptually are factors (such as one containing `"D"` or `"N"` for day or night games) but others are probably better left as strings (many of the columns contain names of starting pitchers, closers, etc.) I know how to convert columns from factors to strings or vice versa, but I don't want to have to scan through 161 columns, making an explicit decision for 75 of them.

The reason I think it important is that I've noticed that conceptually small dataframes obtained by subsetting these game logs are surprisingly large given the need to retain the full factor information. For example, given the dataframe `GL2016` obtained from downloading, unzipping and the reading in the file, `object.size(GL2016)` is about 2.8 MB, and when I use:

```
df <- with(GL2016,GL2016[V7 == "CLE" & V13 == "D",])
```

to extract the home day games played by the Cleveland Indians in 2016, I get a df with 26 rows. 26/2428 (where 2428 is the number of rows in the whole dataframe) is slightly more than 1%, but `object.size(df)` is around 1.3 MB, which is far more than 1% of the size of `GL2016`.

I came up with an ad-hoc solution. I first defined a function:

```
big.factor <- function(v,k){is.factor(v) && length(levels(v)) > k}
```

And then used `mutate_if` from `dplyr` like thus:

```
GL2016 %>% mutate_if(function(v){big.factor(v,30)},as.character) -> GL2016
```

30 is the number of teams in the MLB and I somewhat arbitrarily decided that any factor with more than 30 levels should probably be treated as a string.

After this code has been run, the number of factor variables has been reduced from 75 to 12. It works in the sense that even though now `GL2016` is around 3.2 MB (slightly larger than before), if I now subset the dataframe to pull out the Cleveland day games, the resulting dataframe is just 0.1 MB.

Questions:

1) What criteria (hopefully less ad-hoc than what I used above) are relevant for deciding which character columns should be converted to factors when importing a large data set?

2) I am aware of the cost in terms of memory footprint of converting all character data to factors, but am I incurring any hidden costs (say in processing time) when I convert most of these factors back into strings?

Comment: If you're working with retrosheet data, you may want to use my [retrosheet package](https://github.com/rmscriven/retrosheet).  It's no longer on CRAN but you can install from github.  Although it *is* archived on CRAN.

Comment: @RichScriven Thanks for the tip. That looks nice. So far I've been concentrating on the Lahman datasets, which are very straightforward to extract data from (especially if you know about `plyr`). This past week, I've been delving into Retrosheet data and have noticed how they are vastly more complicated. Does your package parse the play-by-play files (which seem to require actual parsing)?

Comment: The gamelogs?  Yes.  You can use [`getRetrosheet()`](https://github.com/rmscriven/retrosheet/blob/master/R/getRetrosheet.R) for that.  I hope you can still install and use it.  It's been a while since I updated anything, but you can always copy-paste the functions and make the necessary adjustments. There is also [`getPartialGamelog()`](https://github.com/rmscriven/retrosheet/blob/master/R/getPartialGamelog.R) for cases where you don't want the whole gamelog.

Comment: @RichScriven The play-by-play files are the ones which keep track of every change of state throughout every game e.g. inning, runners on base, pitch count, etc. They aren't csv files at all but instead consist of somewhat cryptic variable length lines which look like e.g. `play,6,1,troum001,22,CCB*BX,S7/G.2-3`

Comment: Ah, it doesn't look like it's going to work anyway.  They changed the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, I think what you need to do is:

```
df <- with(GL2016,GL2016[V7 == "CLE" & V13 == "D",])
df <- droplevels(df)
```

`droplevels`function will remove all the unused factor levels, and thus reduce the size of `df` immensely.

Comment: That is quite helpful, so +1.  Being somewhat new to R, I wasn't aware of `droplevels()`. While that does address part of the problem, I still think it would be nice to have some guidance about how to systematically decide which columns to read-in as factors. With these large data sets, I don't have a very clear idea about how I should handle the `stringsAsFactors` parameter, and the extent to which it is a good idea to decide on a column by column basis.

Comment: OK. I just found is a `as.is` argument in read functions. Description: `Its value is either a vector of logicals (values are recycled if necessary), or a vector of numeric or character indices which specify which columns should not be converted to factors.` I never used this and you can have a try.

Comment: Surely you need extra steps for arbitrary character-factor conversion. Generally, factor is easier to manipulate and memory saving.@JohnColeman